# Is there a way to split Trait implementation and defenition across different modules?

Tags: oop, rust, traits, rust-cargo

I'd like to **define** a trait with **many** methods:

```
pub trait DataSetT{
    fn numeric_op_1(&self){...};
    fn numeric_op_2(&self)->f64{...};
    ...
    fn io_op_1(&self) {..};
    fn io_op_2(&self) -> DataFrame {...};
    ...
}
```

Now, if I define all these methods in the same file it would get humongous.
For the sake of clean and visibile code, I'd like to **split these definitions across different files/modules**.

For example numeric operatins would live in:
`src/numerics.rs`
And io operations would live in
`src/io.rs`

Same thing with **implementing** this trait for a Struct (overriding the default trait behaviour).

As soon as I try doing that, I either get *not all trait items implemented* or *confilicting definitions*.

What is the best practice solution in this kind of situtation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without macro you should not be able to split a trait definition over different modules. Where you write `trait MyTrait { .. }` you need to define it.

But you can define multiple traits and have a super trait, like this:

```rust
// src/ops/a.rs
pub trait OpA {
    fn op_a1(&self);
    fn op_a2(&self) -> f64;
}

// src/ops/b.rs
pub trait OpB {
    fn op_b1(&self);
    fn op_b2(&self);
}

// src/ops/mod.rs
pub trait Op: OpA + OpB {}

// src/ops_impl/mod.rs
struct MyOp {}

impl Op for MyOp {}

// src/ops_impl/a.rs
impl OpA for MyOp {
    fn op_a1(&self) {}
    fn op_a2(&self) -> f64 {
        42.0
    }
}

// src/ops_impl/b.rs
impl OpB for MyOp {
    fn op_b1(&self) {}
    fn op_b2(&self) {}
}
```